# Octave database package timestamp from PostgreSQL

Tags: matlab, postgresql, package, octave

Octave database package determines that PostgreSQL timestamp is returned in Octave as 8-byte-time-value positive or negative difference to 2000-01-01 00:00 (int64 scalar, representing microseconds)

e.g. timestamp 2015-12-04 11:22:08 is returned as 502543328000000 in Octave.

How do I convert this to more readable and usable form if I intend to plot time series in Octave?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`datestr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Timing-Utilities.html#XREFdatestr). Note that `datestr` expects the serial date number in units of days and since 1 Jan 0000 as seen from the [`datenum` docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Timing-Utilities.html#XREFdatenum)

> Return the date/time input as a serial day number, with Jan 1, 0000
>   defined as day 1.

So first we would have to convert your PostgreSQL serial number to (a) units of days instead of microseconds and (b) to start from the year 0000 instead of 2000.

```
timestamp = 502543328000000;                   % in microsecond since 2000
timestamp = timestamp / (1000000*60*60*24);    % Days since 2000
timestamp = timestamp + datenum([2000,1,1]);   % Days since 0000
datestr(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")      % Formatted string
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `datestr` format in previous answer, i.e. it returns months in place of minutes and minutes in place of months. Proper format is probably

```
timestamp = input_time;                   % in microsecond since 2000
timestamp = timestamp ./ (1000000*60*60*24);    % Days since 2000
timestamp = timestamp + datenum([2000,1,1]);   % Days since 0000
datestr(timestamp(i), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF")      % Formatted string
```

where FFF stands for miliseconds if needed.